# How to import Lottie component?

Tags: import, compiler-errors, lottie, react-tsx, remix.run

Remix is prone to the [following](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/pages/gotchas) error when using import on top-level components `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')`.

So I've done as they recommend and have the following `imports.server.tsx` file.

```
export * from "lottie-react";
```

Then my component `app.tsx` looks exactly like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/lottie-react-component-2k13t?file=/src/index.js) lottie example.

```
import React from "react";
import * as Lottie from "../imports.server";
import groovyWalkAnimation from "../../public/assets/102875-cinema-clap.json";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>lottie-react - Component</h1>
      <Lottie animationData={groovyWalkAnimation} />;
    </>
  );
}
```

but I get the following error

> JSX element type 'Lottie' does not have any construct or call
> signatures.ts(2604)

**Edit 1:**

The following seems to have worked for imports:

```
imports.server.tsx



import Lottie from "lottie-react";
export default Lottie;



AppTry.tsx



import React from "react";
import Lottie from "../imports.server";

import groovyWalkAnimation from "../../public/assets/102875-cinema-clap.json";

export default function AppTry() {
  // console.log(LottieModule);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>lottie-react - Component</h1>
      <Lottie animationData={groovyWalkAnimation}></Lottie>
    </>
  );
}
```

Now the various paramaters like "animationData" and "autoPlay" pop up on the Lottie component which I assume means the import is working? However I am now getting this error when rendering `AppTry.tsx`?

> react.development.js:220 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid
> -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to
> export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have
> mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `AppTry`.

**Edit 2:**

```
import { useLottie } from "lottie-react";
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import groovyWalkAnimation from "../../public/assets/102875-cinema-clap.json";

const Example = () => {
  const options = {
    animationData: groovyWalkAnimation,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
  };

  const { View } = useLottie(options);

  return View;
};

const Example1 = () => {
  return <Lottie animationData={groovyWalkAnimation} />;
};

export const TopicOverview = () => {

  return (
    <div className="space-y-20">
      <Example1></Example1>
      <Example></Example>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled to get this working in Remix.
You can do the lazy load import somewhere higher up in the tree too.

```
import type { LottiePlayer } from "@lottiefiles/lottie-player";
import { useEffect } from "react";

interface LottieCompProps {
  src: LottiePlayer["src"];
  style?: Partial<LottiePlayer["style"]>;
}

function LottieComp({ src, style = {} }: LottieCompProps): JSX.Element | null {
  // NB: otherwise, will cause app to crash. see https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/constraints#third-party-module-side-effects
    useEffect(() => {
      import("@lottiefiles/lottie-player");
    },[]);

  if (typeof document === "undefined") return null;
  return (
    //@ts-expect-error dynamic import
    <lottie-player
      autoplay
      loop
      mode="normal"
      src={typeof src === "string" ? src : JSON.stringify(src)}
      style={{
        ...{
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
        },
        ...style,
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default LottieComp;
```

Comment: This is the answer that helped me out. Could the PO select one as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has to do with your way of importing Lottie.

Shouldn't you import Lottie like this?:

```
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
```

Comment: As I said above, remix has this issue. See here https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/pages/gotchas hence the import statement. If I try `import Lottie from "../imports.server";` I get the following error "Module imports.server has no default export"

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gobli is on the right track. You may need to play around with your imports.server.tsx a bit more (eg based on the error message you posted maybe define Lottie as the default export?).  I don't know how `export * from...` handles defaults, but that's worth looking into. 

`import * as Lottie` is always going to fail due to the fact that you're importing the entire module as Lottie, whereas  `import Lottie from "lottie-react";` is importing a specific item from the module.

Comment: I've edited my post, made at-least some progress. Any ideas? Does that seem right?

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't need the imports.server for Lottie, as it's a Client side library and the Remix Gotcha that you point out refers to server side code. 
Maybe the ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')``` comes from another place?

Comment: Hmm but where from, I've implemented the components exactly as [they](https://github.com/Gamote/lottie-react) do in their example. I'll edit now and show you what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in  my `root.tsx`, an `ErrorBoundary()` function that called an `<UnexpectedErrors/>` component.
This same component was being called in various `slug.tsx` files. For some reason remix did not like this.

Having two different `<UnexpectedErrors/>` and `<UnexpectedErrors2/>` components - one for the `slug.tsx` files and one for the `index.tsx` files fixed this.